# C++ Add LPSTR buffer to char array

Tags: c++, arrays, char, lpstr

Here is the situation:
I have a class in which has a method in which I have a loop that overwrites a buffer with a new letter every iteration and the buffer's datatype is LPSTR.

My question is, how I could take all the letters that are generated in the loop and return them as a char array?

Comment: LPSTR is a typedef for `char *`, so it must already be pointing into a char array.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood you correctly, but from what I read I gathered you're trying to do something like this:

```
char buffer[256];
for(int i = 0, char c; (c = someAction()) != NULL && i < 256; ++i) {
    buffer[i] = c;
}
```

Comment: Better check in the loop condition that i < 256, or whatever the buffer size is.

Comment: Good point.  I kind of just throw out some rough code, but you're right I should have done that.